# Finding Convergence of series $\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{3k}{k^2+4}$

Tags: convergence-divergence

Finding Convergence of series $$\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{3k}{k^2+4}$$ using Integral test or Divergences Test.

What i try

Let $$\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{3k}{k^2+4}=3/5+6/8+\sum^{\infty}_{k=3}\frac{3k}{k^2+4}$$

Let $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{3x}{x^2+4}.$ Then $f'(x)<0$ for $x>2$

So using Integral Test

$$\int^{\infty}_{3}\frac{3x}{x^2+4}dx=1.5\ln|x^2+4|\bigg|^{\infty}_{3}\rightarrow -\infty$$

So series is Diverges.

But when i apply Divergence Test.

In $$\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{3k}{k^2+4}$$. Then its limit goes to $0$

Means this series is converges.

Plese tell me which one is right. Thanks

Comment: Your second argument is not valid. What is the statement of the Divergence Test?

Comment: Means first one is Right. Professor

Comment: The correct wording is "this series converges" or "is convergent".

Comment: Remember, it's literally a test for divergence. It tells you nothing about convergence. Only a non zero limit is informative (meaning divergence). A zero limit gives no information.

Comment: @jacky You wrote $\to -\infty$ instead of $\to \infty$. Otherwise your first method is correct. Also, there is a much simpler method to show divergence.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way you can verify the series diverges .

$\dfrac{3k}{k^2+4}\gt\dfrac{3k}{(k+2)^2}=\dfrac{k+2k}{(k+2)^2}\gt\dfrac{k+2}{(k+2)^2}=\dfrac{1}{k+2}$

$\implies\displaystyle\sum\dfrac{3k}{k^2+4}\gt\displaystyle\sum\dfrac1k=\infty$

Answer (score 1):

The divergence test is conclusive when the limit of the sequence is nonzero. When this limit is zero, there is nothing you can say.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{3k}{k^2+4}> \sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{3k}{k^2}=3\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac 1k$$

As the harmonic series, $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1k$, is divergent, it follows that the series diverges.